# CQLSession initialization error while executing triggers with Apache Cassandra 4.0.11

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-4.0

I am getting errors during CQLSession initialization while executing triggers. The contact-points are `[ “127.0.0.1:9042” ]` with SSL enabled.

Seems like its caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'cluster_name' is already in use
```

and this is the error:

```
ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-01-18 00:10:35,776 ErrorMessage.java:457 - Unexpected exception during request
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while executing trigger on table with ID: 646d8860-7dfa-11ee-a2c6-7d8ff396b60d
    at org.apache.cassandra.triggers.TriggerExecutor.executeInternal(TriggerExecutor.java:247)
    at org.apache.cassandra.triggers.TriggerExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.mutateWithTriggers(StorageProxy.java:1037)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.executeWithoutCondition(ModificationStatement.java:476)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.execute(ModificationStatement.java:454)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processStatement(QueryProcessor.java:244)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:337)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:324)
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.messages.QueryMessage.execute(QueryMessage.java:108)
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Request.execute(Message.java:242)
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Dispatcher.processRequest(Dispatcher.java:86)
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Dispatcher.processRequest(Dispatcher.java:106)
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Dispatcher.lambda$dispatch$0(Dispatcher.java:70)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:165)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:137)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:119)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=73869e00): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [cassandra|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException.copy(AllNodesFailedException.java:141)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835)
    at com.fanatics.dao.common.AbstractCassandraStore.<init>(AbstractCassandraStore.java:49)
    at com.fanatics.dao.triggers.CDCQueries.<init>(CDCQueries.java:38)
    at com.fanatics.dao.triggers.CartSchemaTriggers.augment(CartSchemaTriggers.java:43)
    at org.apache.cassandra.triggers.TriggerExecutor.executeInternal(TriggerExecutor.java:235)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [cassandra|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.fail(ProtocolInitHandler.java:356)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.writeListener(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:87)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:184)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.send(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:76)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.send(ProtocolInitHandler.java:193)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler.onRealConnect(ProtocolInitHandler.java:124)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ConnectInitHandler.lambda$connect$0(ConnectInitHandler.java:57)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:605)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:300)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:335)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        ... 2 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.InFlightHandler.write(InFlightHandler.java:96)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:764)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:808)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1025)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:294)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.send(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:75)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'cluster_name' is already in use
        at io.netty.util.ConstantPool.createOrThrow(ConstantPool.java:109)
        at io.netty.util.ConstantPool.newInstance(ConstantPool.java:91)
        at io.netty.util.AttributeKey.newInstance(AttributeKey.java:55)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.DriverChannel.<clinit>(DriverChannel.java:50)
        ... 30 common frames omitted
```

The application config used in the triggers is:

```
datastax-java-driver {
    basic {
        config-reload-interval = 0
        session-name = "cassandra"
        session-keyspace = "orders"
        contact-points = [ "127.0.0.1:9042" ]
        load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter = "dc3"
        request {
            consistency = LOCAL_QUORUM
            serial-consistency = LOCAL_SERIAL
            timeout = 6 seconds
        }
    }
    advanced {
        ssl-engine-factory {
            class = DefaultSslEngineFactory
            hostname-validation = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is missing details info on here as to which driver and version you're using here in the application, so I'm making some assumptions here as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.17.0</version><!-- this is latest as of this writing -->
</dependency>
```

Since you've encryption enabled, you also need to pass the truststore details by updating your config file with info as below,

```
datastax-java-driver {
...
  advanced {
    ssl-engine-factory {
      class = DefaultSslEngineFactory
      truststore-path = "/path/to/certs/your_truststore.jks"
      truststore-password = "truststore password"
      hostname-validation = false
    }
...
}
```

I'd also check [the `cluster_name` property on the C* node's `cassandra.yaml` file](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0.11/conf/cassandra.yaml#L11) to see if it is correctly mentioned. Are you see any other errors in the `system.log`/`debug.log` on the server-side during this - this may also help uncover additional details.

Check out [the **DataStax Java Driver** configuration docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/configuration/reference/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that both your Java app and Cassandra cluster are hosted on the same machine otherwise your app will not be able to connect to the Cassandra instance if it's only listening for client connections on `localhost`.

If so, you need to perform additional steps to connect to the cluster:

1. export the Cassandra node's certificate, and
2. configure the driver with the certificate's `truststore`, `keystore` and passwords.

For example:

```
  advanced {
    ssl-engine-factory {
      class = DefaultSslEngineFactory
      hostname-validation = false

      # truststore + keystore you created and associated passwords
      truststore-path = /path/to/exported/client.truststore
      truststore-password = truststore_password
      keystore-path = /path/to/exported/client.keystore
      keystore-password = keystore_password
    }
  }
```

The detailed steps along with examples are documented in [the Java driver SSL page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/ssl/). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Erick for your response.
Yes I am running a Java Trigger jar on a Cassandra Node. Hence while building a session, I am using `localhost`.
The Cassandra node has truststore and keystore on its cassandra.yml and as per your suggestion I added those in the config
ssl-engine-factory {
 class = DefaultSslEngineFactory
 truststore-path = "/opt/cassandra/tls/truststore.jks"
 truststore-password = "truststore_password"
 keystore-path = "/opt/cassandra/tls/keystore.jks"
 keystore-password = "keystore_password"
 hostname-validation = false
} 

I am still getting the above error

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'cluster_name' is already in use"

Specifically this. 


My versions used
Apache Cassandra version: 4.0.11
Cassandra DB version: 4.0.6
Cassandra Driver version: 4.17.0

Comment: But is Cassandra listening for clients on `localhost`? The error suggests otherwise. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Erick & Madhavan for your responses.
Yes I am running a Java Trigger jar on a Cassandra Node. Hence using `localhost` as a contact point while building a CqlSession.

Versions used: (Assuming no incompatibility)

```
Apache Cassandra version: 4.0.11
Cassandra DB Node version: 4.0.6
Cassandra Driver version: 4.17.0
```

The Cassandra node has truststore and keystore paths on its cassandra.yml and as per your suggestion I added those in the config.

```
    basic {
        config-reload-interval = 0
        session-name = "cassandra"
        session-keyspace = "orders"
        contact-points = [ "127.0.0.1:9042" ]
        load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter = "dc3"
        request {
            consistency = LOCAL_QUORUM
            serial-consistency = LOCAL_SERIAL
            timeout = 6 seconds
        }
    }
    advanced {
        ssl-engine-factory {
            class = DefaultSslEngineFactory
            truststore-path = "/opt/cassandra/tls/truststore.jks"
            truststore-password = "truststore password"
            keystore-path = "/opt/cassandra/tls/keystore.jks"
            keystore-password = "keystore password"
            hostname-validation = false
        }
    }
}
```

I still see the above error stack
specifically

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'cluster_name' is already in use`

There is a `cluster_name` set on `cassandra.yml` on C* node.

Any pointers on this error is appreciated. Thank you!